# A Hyperelliptic Compact Riemann Surface $X$ is a 2-sheeted cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

It is stated in [Geometry of Algebraic Curves by Harris](https://staff.math.su.se/shapiro/UIUC/curvesHarris.pdf) that there are two equivalent definitions of a hyperelliptic curve $X$:

(i) There exists a degree $2$ meromorphic global function of $X$.

(ii) $X$ is expressible as a $2$-sheeted cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

**Question:** How are these equivalent?

I have introductory knowledge of embeddings of curves in projective space, and I understand that the equivalence should follow somewhat as follows:

Condition $(i) \Rightarrow$ we have a degree $2$ divisor $D$ on $X$ such that $\dim(H^0(O_C(D)))\geq 2$

$\Rightarrow$ we have a map $\phi_D:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1=\mathbb{P}H^0(O_C(D))^*$ given by $p\mapsto H_p\subset H^0(O_C(D))$, where $H_p$ is the hyperplane in the vector space given by $\sigma\in H^0(O_C(D))|(\sigma)\geq p$, $(\bullet)$ denoting the divisor.

How do we get from here that the map is degree $2$ and thus condition $(ii)$? Also, how do we show the converse?

Comment: I'd think of it in more naive terms: A meromorphic function on a complex curve is a holomorphic map to the projective line (i.e., there are no points of indeterminacy), and a non-constant holomorphic map on a connected curve is a branched covering. But perhaps you're working over other fields than $\mathbf{C}$...?

Comment: Since $C$ is a compact Riemann surface, you may realize $C \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ as an algebraic curve in projective n-space over the field $k$ of complex numbers. Any non-constant rational function $s$ defines a finite surjective morphism $\phi_s: C \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1_k$. You must prove that $\phi_s$ has degree $2$.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255500/hartshorne-chapter-1-exercise-6-4-maps-of-curves-and-function-fields